# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.ListView

Tags: java, android

Other people have similar errors, although this one is different, speciialy because of the getListView()

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.ListView cookiemaster.cookieclicker.MainActivity$ItemsList.getListView()' on a null object reference

```
  @Override
public void TimerTick()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            totalCookies.setText("Total: " + Beautify.CommaSeparate((int)(Game.getInstance().getTotal())));
           CookiesPerSec.setText(Beautify.CommaSeparateDouble(Math.round(Game.getInstance().getCps() * 100.0) / 100.0) + " CPS");


            try{ ItemsList.getListView().invalidateViews(); }
            catch(IllegalStateException e){}
        }
    });
}
```

Logcat:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.ListView cookiemaster.cookieclicker.MainActivity$ItemsList.getListView()' on a null object reference
            at cookiemaster.cookieclicker.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:136)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: If (app != null && app.hasError) app.postLogcat().

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you please re type my code implementing what you said.

Comment: I am saying, post your logcat.

Comment: I thought people of Stackoverflow would have enjoyed the joke!

Comment: Post all of your code. Where is `ItemsList` being initiated?

Comment: https://github.com/CookieMaster/CookieClicker

Comment: You are never initiating you `ItemsList` in your `onCreate`. https://github.com/CookieMaster/CookieClicker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/cookiemaster/cookieclicker/MainActivity.java

Comment: Very confused, its looks like I initialized it but it isn't? What do I have to add because I cant think straight

Comment: You are never initialized your `ItemsList` in your `onCreate()`.

Comment: *face desk* Thank you very much

Comment: Since this is closed and I can't "answer" it, you can probably just delete this question. Goodluck!